# For cases created in Lightning from Account page, Account field is erased

Tags: case, lightning-experience

In Lightning Experience, If we are creating a Case from the Account related section as a sales profile user, the `Account Name` field is cleared immediately after the case is created.

This is happening in Spring'17 Sandbox, Winter'17 Developer Edition and Winter'17 Enterprise Edition.

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. Login as a Sales Profile user in Lightning experience.
2. Go to any account, while on the Related section, scroll down to the Cases Related list and click on the `New` button as in this screenshot.
   [image]
3. It would open a New case creation form with Account Name already populated(because we are already on the Account page):
   [image]
4. Once the case is created, if you go to the case details page, the Account Name field has blank value..Not sure why?

[image]

**NOTE:**

1. If I login as the same user and create case in Classic experience,
   it does not happen.
2. I verified and there are no workflow rules,triggers or process builder running on the case object.

Anyone experienced this issue? Any clues?

Comment: Salesforce support came back and opened it as known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jimxAAA